# 403 error - unable to login into admin

Tags: 6

Recently I created two pages for http 403 and 404 and assigned them so that on error those two will be shown.
But today when I tried to login to my admin in my site: http://www.indiacustomercare.com/admin
it is giving error "Error 403 - Permission Denied".

The message:"Unfortunately the page you are looking for is not accessible by you." is from the page I had assigned for http 403.

Looks like I did some silly mistake, my other two D6 sites have no problem logging in.

How do I login into admin again?

Comment: Maybe you have also made some changes to the .htaccess??Can you show that?

Comment: What method did you use to assign/setup the 404/403 pages?

Comment: I did not change .htaccess. What I did was to create two nodes with 404 and 403 error messages and assigned them in admin/settings/error-reporting. Also please don't forget to click the site admin url and see the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may seem a silly suggestion, but have you tried going to /user rather then /admin the former being the login page, the latter being the admin pages once logged in?

Comment: very nice! It worked! Nice silly suggestion!